# Getting Facebook ID from contact list

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm working on an application which has an option to share certain items on Facebook. I know how to post them on user's own wall, but i'd like to add an option to share it on friend's wall too.

So, is there a way to have the app open phone contact list and pick a Facebook contact from there? Or for that matter what would be the wisest way to go for it? I can do the actual posting part, i just need a way to choose the friend's ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using me... [graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=user_token](http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=user_token) assuming you have read_friendslist permission.

It will return something like:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
  "name": "Randy John.", 
  "id": "148dg50945"
  }, 
  {
  "name": "Shannon", 
  "id": "148740224611711"
  }, 
  {
  "name": "Someone ", 
  "id": "1000000"
  }, 
  {
  "name": "Mary Oconal", 
  "id": "100000318920"
 } 
}
```

Once you get the ID, you then could do another call to get the friend info([graph.facebook.com/111111111?access_token=access_token](http://graph.facebook.com/111111111/?access_token=user_token))

```
{ 
  "id": "111111111", 
  "name": "Randy Johnson", 
  "first_name": "Randy", 
  "last_name": "Johnson", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=111111111", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "updated_time": "2011-08-17T17:22:19+0000", 
  "type": "user"
}
```

And of course you can get even more info about them by specifying more fields by appending fields after access_token(e.g. &fields=gender, education, etc)

Comment: I think he wants a 'friend selector' dialog, though, e.g. from phone contacts

Comment: @Rup indeed that's what i'm after.

Comment: Which you would populate via the friends list you can't get email or phone number... so not sure how you could match it without previously  linking your contact to facebook.

Comment: I know i might have to work with Graph API, but i was hoping there was something like PhoneNumberChooserTask for facebook accounts so i could use the WP7's own contact list. So that's not an option then?

Comment: You're probably correct. I was hoping I just were bad at searching since I couldn't find anything myself. I will mark this as an answer later if nothing else shows up.

Answer (score 1):

In the current release, the OS does not share information about about, such as IDs and tokens. The only interaction with these accounts is the `Share*` tasks.

Your only choice here is to authenticate separately in your application and provide your own friend selector using the Graph API, as mentioned by Nix.